# How can I implement pygame.sprite.spritecollide to my pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So far I have a game working with background, WASD movement, window boundaries and a bunch of other stuff.

I want to use [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide)

If you look on that link, you will see that it says the sprites need `rect` attributes. All I have is `pygame.image.load("mysprite")`, and im unsure how I can correctly give it a rect attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the pygame documentation talks about sprites, it talks about using the [`Sprite`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) class.

To have this work, each `Sprite` needs a `rect` (an instance of `Rect`) and an `image` (and instace of `Surface`) attribute.

`pygame.image.load` returns a single Surface, and you can set the `Sprite`'s `image` attribute to this `Surface`.

Here's an example of using sprites with `spritecollide`:

```
import pygame
import math
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# some helpful vector math functions
def normalize(v):
    vmag = magnitude(v)
    return [v[i]/vmag  for i in range(len(v))]
def magnitude(v):
    return math.sqrt(sum(v[i]*v[i] for i in range(len(v))))
def add(u, v):
    return [ u[i]+v[i] for i in range(len(u)) ]

class Paddle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, start_pos, up_key, down_key):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        # the image is just a white rect
        self.image = pygame.surface.Surface((20, 100))
        self.image.fill(pygame.color.Color('White'))
        self.image.set_colorkey(pygame.color.Color('Black'))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=start_pos)
        # using a mask so we can use pixel perfect collision
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
        self.up_key, self.down_key = up_key, down_key
    def update(self, pressed):
        if pressed[self.up_key]:   self.rect.move_ip(0, -3)
        if pressed[self.down_key]: self.rect.move_ip(0,  3)
        # keep the paddle inside the screen
        self.rect.clamp_ip(pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect())

class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, start_pos):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        # the image is just a white ball
        self.image = pygame.surface.Surface((20, 20))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=start_pos)
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, pygame.color.Color('White'), self.image.get_rect().center, 10)
        self.image.set_colorkey(pygame.color.Color('Black'))
        # using a mask so we can use pixel perfect collision
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
        # the vector we use to move the ball
        self.move_v = (1, 0.7)
        # store the absolute position in self.pos
        # because a rect can only use integers
        self.pos = self.rect.center
    def update(self, pressed):
        # check if the ball collides with any other sprite
        collide = [s for s in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.groups()[0], False, pygame.sprite.collide_mask) if s != self]
        if collide:
            # warning: this does not handle the case of the ball hits 
            # the top or bottom of the paddle, only the sides.
            self.move_v = [-self.move_v[0], self.move_v[1]]

        # check if the ball would go out of screen
        display = pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect()
        if self.rect.top < display.top and self.move_v[1] < 0 or \
           self.rect.bottom > display.bottom and self.move_v[1] > 0:
            self.move_v = [self.move_v[0], -self.move_v[1]]

        # apply a constant speed and update the position
        move_vector = [c * 4 for c in normalize(self.move_v)]
        self.pos = add(self.rect.center, move_vector)
        self.rect.center = map(int, self.pos)

player1 = Paddle((30,  190), pygame.K_w , pygame.K_s)
player2 = Paddle((590, 190), pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_DOWN)
ball = Ball(screen.get_rect().center)
sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(player1, player2, ball)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: break
    else:
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        sprites.update(pressed)
        screen.fill(pygame.color.Color('black'))
        sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
        continue
    break
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I too Tried many times and designed to get this output: you can use this to identify the collision's between two to three sprites like I have done in here:
As you use it two of them move and as you use arrow key's one of them move try running it yourself just add an image.png with it and you will understand it a way better

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import os
import sys
import math
import random
class wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('image.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.move_direction = 1
        self.move_counter = 0

    def draw(self,win):
        win.blit(self.image,(self.rect.x,self.rect.y))

class wall2(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('raj.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.move_direction = 1
        self.move_counter = 0

    def draw(self,win):
        win.blit(self.image,(self.rect.x,self.rect.y))

def redrawWin(win):
    win.fill((240,240,240))
    pygame.draw.rect(win,(0,0,0),(0,400,w,10))
    box.draw(win)
    enemy.draw(win)
    enemy2.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()

w,h=800,500
x1=50
x2=600
a=0
win=pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run=True
while run:
    box=wall(x1,340,70,80)
    enemy=wall(x2,340,70,80)
    enemy2=wall2(x2+100, 340)
    for event in pygame.event.get():  
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[K_LEFT]:
            x1-=10
        if keys[K_RIGHT]:
            x1+=10
        if keys[K_d]:
            x2+=10
        if keys[K_a]:
            x2-=10
    sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(enemy,enemy2)
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(box,sprites,False):
        print(pygame.sprite.spritecollide(box,sprites,False))
        print(True,a)
        a+=1
    clock.tick(20)
    redrawWin(win)
```

It is pretty simple to do it I have taken 2 classes with the same image and then made to collide with them if you want to prevent their collision then just go forward and pause the keys when they collide